# Python ZSI Client error

Tags: python, wsdl, zsi

I am a newbie with web services and I really need your help.

I have an existing WSDL, and based on my research, the easiest to use is ZSI for python. It has a *wsdl2py* and *wsdl2dispatch* scripts which generates the code based from the existing *WSDL*. I now have the 3 files it has generated (server.py, service.py, services_types.py) and I have created a client (myClient.py) to call an action in the service. I am having an issue in service.py

```
def Set(self, request):
    if isinstance(request, TryService_Set) is False:
        raise TypeError, "%s incorrect request type" % (request.__class__)
    kw = {}
    # no input wsaction
    self.binding.Send(None, None, request, soapaction="Set", **kw)
    # no output wsaction
    response = self.binding.Receive(TryService_SetResponse.typecode)
    return response
```

The error that I get is:

File `"C:\Python27\lib\urlparse.py", line 182, in urlsplit`

```
 i = url.find(':')`
```

due to this line:

```
 self.binding.Send(None, None, request, soapaction="Set", **kw)
```

Hope you can enlighten me, I don't have anyone to ask. Or am I doing the right thing, i.e. using ZSI?

Thanks!